# Ruby 1.8.7 add 10 minutes to time object

Tags: ruby

So I'm new to ruby and I'm stuck using 1.8.7 at the moment. I'm trying to add 10 minutes to a time object after reading the documentation and I'm having no such luck.

```
require "time"

curr_time = Time.now.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
curr_time = curr_time + 600
```

And then I get an Error saying

> '+': can't convert Fixnum into String (TypeError)

Any ideas?

Comment: BTW, why do you use outdated 1.8.7 version?

Comment: @MarekLipka we're running an older OS on one of our boxes and this is the latest version compatible. No one uses Ruby except for this background script I'm running so its not a priority

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's because in your `curr_time` variable you have the result of `strftime` method call, which is `String`, not `Time` instance. To add 10 minutes, you can do:

```
curr_time = Time.now
(curr_time + 600).strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Answer (score 4):

You should "add time" to `Time` object itself, not to its `string` representation:

```
require "time"

curr_time = Time.now
curr_time = curr_time + 600
formatted = curr_time.strftime("%d-%b-%Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Hope that solves your problem!